# 3 duplicate ACKs in TCP

Tags: tcp

If a client receives 3 duplicate ACKs in TCP then it will half the window size and switch from slow start to congestion avoidance.

Will it retransmit the next `window_size` segments, or will it just retransmit the one?

(If necessary this assumes TCP Reno)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it only *immediately* retransmits the one packet, under the assumption/hope that only the one packet was dropped, and the rest got through and are buffered at the receiver, just waiting for that one hole to be filled before the receiver TCP stack can pass the whole buffer up to the receiving application.

Comment: Can you please provide any reference for your answer ?